# How to fix error code 110 in agora? unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

i am using agora voice for sound system in unity. but I am getting an error with the code error 110. sdk is up to date.

I read the agora docs, did the sdk update.

I get and use token from railway.app but it says invalid token

here is my code:

```
    IEnumerator
FetchToken(string url, string channel, string userId, int TimeToLive) /* , Action<string> callback = null */
{
    int role = 1;
    UnityWebRequest request =
        UnityWebRequest
            .Get(string
                .Format("{0}/rtc/{1}/{2}/uid/{3}/?expiry={4}",
                url,
                channel,
                role,
                userId,
                TimeToLive));

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(request.error);

        /* callback(null); */
        yield break;
    }
    AgoraToken tokenInfo =
        JsonUtility.FromJson<AgoraToken>(request.downloadHandler.text);

    /* callback(tokenInfo.rtcToken); */
    fetchedToken = tokenInfo.rtcToken;
}
```

Comment: Ok so thats how you got a token. Is that the code making the error or so you get the error when using the token?

Comment: I get the token successfully, when I use it I get an error.

when i create a static token from agora i don't get an error, i can join the room

Comment: Then show how you use it?  Make a minimal recreatable example. People cant help without decent info

Comment: First of all, my apologies, it's the last line of the code snippet I gave above.
fetchedToken = tokenInfo.rtcToken;
I replace the line with the token I created manually from agora: fetchedToken = "manual token from agora";

it works this way.